# Yahoo Pipes JSON to Database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, yahoo-pipes

I want to make an auto complete system using Jquery from the yahoo pipes JSON, but the autocomplete only pulls from the latest entries and anything from previous days will not show.

I created a Yahoo Pipe and have outputted the result to JSON. How can one push the results of  a database and then retrieve it later?

Here is my working example: http://www.tylerharpool.com/json
I just want to be able to search for previous entries.

Comment: Is the goal to come up with a way to do this entirely in Pipes ie. without your own server?

Comment: Yes, I would like to do it entirely in pipes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **YQL** module will allow the pipe to access small storage pockets (100k in size, and you can 1000 of them) where you can keep and retrieve data at a later date.

**HOWEVER:** you don't actually need pipes to store information

The previous days results could be also be kept inside the visitors PC, using the **window.localStorage.setItem** feature found in most web browsers. There is a jquery plugin version and several others so Google around for one that you prefer.